# Sharing work specified in Postgres table between multiple Python workers

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using SQL Alchemy with Postgres. I have a table called Jobs which is defined as below:

```
class Job(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    processed = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    data = Column(String)
```

Let's assume the work being done to process the data takes a minute. I'd like to spawn multiple workers which take a job off the table and process it. When a worker queries for a job it looks for the first unprocessed job that is not currently being processed (order does not matter).

I was thinking of using `select` with `with_for_update` to lock the row which will be processed so that there are no clashes of workers processing the same thing:

```
job_to_process = session.query(Job).filter_by(processed=False).with_for_update().first_or_none()
```

The problem is that if worker A starts up it will get job 1 and then worker B starts up while worker A is processing job 1 but the above query will try to return job 1 to worker B and fail until the lock is removed. Is there any way to get worker B to run the above query to return the first unlocked row and ignore the locked row?

Comment: Looks like you can specify `SKIP LOCKED` in your pg queries: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#SKIP_LOCKED which sounds like what you are looking for. I'm not sure how to specify it on a sqla query though.

Comment: Actually, seems there is support for that in sqlalchemy: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/changelog/migration_11.html#support-for-for-update-skip-locked-for-no-key-update-for-key-share

Comment: Ah, Thank you!! :D Do you want to add an answer and I will mark as such?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres has the `SKIP LOCKED` option, and the use case they specify in [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html) seems to closely align with your goals here:

> ...any selected rows that cannot be immediately locked are skipped.
>   Skipping locked rows provides an inconsistent view of the data, so
>   this is not suitable for general purpose work, but can be used to
>   avoid lock contention with multiple consumers accessing a queue-like
>   table.

On the SQLAlchemy side of the equation, the [`with_for_update()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/selectable.html?highlight=skip_locked#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.CompoundSelect.with_for_update) method that you are already using provides the `skip_locked` Boolean flag:

> ...will render FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED on Oracle and PostgreSQL dialects or FOR SHARE 
>   SKIP LOCKED if read=True is also specified.

So, appears that Postgresql and SQLAlchemy have you covered:)